# React Testing Library testing router inside a router error

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I want to test my react AppRoutes component using the test case below.
But I am encountering an error saying that you cannot render a Router inside another Router.

```
console.error
          Error: Uncaught [Error: You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app.]
```

My Test Case:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MemoryRouter, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppRoutes from './AppRoutes';

test('renders App component when route is /', () => {
  render(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
      
        <AppRoutes />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  const appComponent = screen.getByText(/This page is created using react/i);
  expect(appComponent).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

AppRoutes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App'
import AboutMe from './AboutMe';

function AppRoutes() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
                <Route path="about" element={<AboutMe />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default AppRoutes;
```

This is how I use it in my App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          This page is created using react.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://www.linkedin.com"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          My Linkedin Profile
        </a>
        <Link to="about"> About Me</Link>
      </header>

      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear, you can't render the `<BrowserRouter/>` inside the `<MemoryRouter/>`. Both `<BrowserRouter/>` and `<MemoryRouter/>` components are implemented based on the `<Router/>` component. See source code of [`<MemoryRouter/>`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/ef0d0d70cea8f8979b42e1d7ef50fc39dd72d9cd/packages/react-router/lib/components.tsx#L218) component and [`<BrowserRouter/>`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/ef0d0d70cea8f8979b42e1d7ef50fc39dd72d9cd/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L737) component. The error throws in [`<Router/>`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/ef0d0d70cea8f8979b42e1d7ef50fc39dd72d9cd/packages/react-router/lib/components.tsx#L423) component.

```
  invariant(
    !useInRouterContext(),
    `You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>.` +
      ` You should never have more than one in your app.`
  );
```

[`useInRouterContext`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.21.1/hooks/use-in-router-context#useinroutercontext) hook returns `true` if the component is being rendered in the context of a `<Router>`, `false` otherwise.

You can move the `<BrowserRouter/>` to the `index.tsx` file. Define the routes in the `<AppRoutes/>` component, then you can render the `<AppRoutes/>` as children of `<MemoryRouter/>`. We don't have to test the entry file `index.tsx`.

Example:

`AppRoutes.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {  Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default AppRoutes;
```

`index.tsx`:

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppRoutes from './AppRoutes';

const domNode = document.getElementById('root') as Element;
const root = createRoot(domNode);

root.render(
  <Router>
    <AppRoutes />
  </Router>,
);
```

`AppRoutes.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import AppRoutes from './AppRoutes';
import React from 'react';

test('renders App component when route is /', () => {
  render(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
      <AppRoutes />
    </MemoryRouter>,
  );

  const appComponent = screen.getByText(/This page is created using react/i);
  expect(appComponent).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/77786066/AppRoutes.test.tsx
  √ renders App component when route is / (22 ms)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.107 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

package version:

```json
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.21.1",
"jest": "^29.7.0",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
```